# jQuery DIV Container disappears after 1 sec

Tags: jquery, html

I am filling a hidden div container with ajax content by pressing a button.
As soon as the button is pressed, I want the container to show up with the new content.

This has been working fine for me using the following method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.display').css({'display':'none'});

    $('.button').click(function() { 
        $('.display').show(); return false; 
    });
});
```

Since I have a lot of content, the display div shows up sometimes before and until the DOM is loaded.

I have solved this, by hiding the display div in the stylesheet.

The problem now is, as soon as I press the button, the div container shows up for one second and then disappears even though I did not write in my jquery code to hide it.

Comment: try `$('.display').stop().show();`

Comment: Then you have some other code messing with it... check it out.

Comment: why don't you remove `$('.display').css({'display':'none'});` if you have already hidden it in css?

Comment: i did remove $('.display').css({'display':'none'}); from the jquery. the .stop().show() method does not work either. it is probably some other code messing with it. Thank you guys for the fast responses

Answer (score 0):

check like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.display').css({'display':'none'});

$('.button').click(function() { 
         $('.display').css({'display':'block'});
         return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: _"The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling **.css('display', 'block')**"_